# How was Lord Clayman's awakening as a true Demon Lord supposed to work?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

In episode 40 ('The Congress Dances') of *That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime*, it's speculated that Demon Lord Clayman wants to attack the Animal Kingdom of Eurazania to awaken as a true Demon Lord. When the battle unfolds, it's not Demon Lord Clayman who is conducting the assault but rather an army of 30,000.

In episode 33 ('Putting Everything on the Line'), Rimuru says "*taking out the invading army myself is a necessary part of* [becoming a Demon Lord]".

My question is...  if Rimuru needed to kill 10,000 humans himself and capture their souls, then why doesn't Demon Lord Clayman need to kill 10,000 people himself? Why is it sufficient for his subordinates to do it?

Also, if that was Demon Lord Clayman's goal, then couldn't he have killed 10,000 of his own men to awaken as a true Demon Lord? Or maybe he could have taken the souls of his men when they died, even if he hadn't planned on them dying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In episode 33, Rimuru is actually lying to everyone and he is not the person that needs to make the kills. The truth of the matter is anyone connected to him such as everyone he named could be doing it instead, and this is better explained in the light novel and the manga. Clayman was planning on the awakening by killing a large number of people, but he did not know the exact numbers. He had been killing human slaves that he had bought, but that had not been enough, so the war with Tempest and the Beast Kingdom was his next move.

As for why he didn't kill his own troops, I would wager that is because he didn't know how many he needed to kill and didn't want to make himself weaker.